# How to loop awk command over row values

Tags: awk

I would like to use awk to search for a particular word in the first column of a table and print the value in the 6th column. I understand how to do this searching one word at time using something along the lines of:

```
awk '$1 == "<insert-word>" { print $6 }' file.txt
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to loop this over a list of words in a row?

For example If I had a table like file1.txt below:

```
cat file1.txt 
dna1    dna4    dna5
dna3    dna6    dna2
dna7    dna8    dna9
```

Could I loop over each value in row 1 and search for this word in column 1 of file2.txt below, each time printing the value of column 6? Then do this for row 2, 3 and so on...

```
cat file2
dna1    0   229 7   0   4   0   0
dna2    0   296 39  2   1   3   100
dna3    0   255 15  0   6   0   0
dna4    0   209 3   0   0   0   0
dna5    0   253 14  2   3   7   100
dna6    0   897 629 7   8   1   100
dna7    0   214 4   0   9   0   0
dna8    0   255 15  0   2   0   0
dna9    0   606 338 8   3   1   100
```

So an example looping the awk over row 1 of file 1 would return the numbers 4, 0 and 3.

The looping the command over row 2 would return the numbers 6, 8 and 1

And finally looping over row 3 would return the number 9, 2, 3

An example output might be

```
4    0    3
6    8    1
9    2    3
```

What I would really like to to is sum the total value of the numbers returned for each row. I just wasn't sure if this would be possible...

An example output of this would be

```
7
15
14
```

But I am not worried if this step isn't possible using awk as I could just do it separately

Hope this makes sense

Cheers
Ollie

Comment: Please post the sample output too in your post.

Comment: Yes perhaps this is a bad example since I've just given the head of two large files and there are not any matches between the two. But if row 1 of file1 for example contained TRINITY_DN100001_c0_g1_i1 and TRINITY_DN100004_c0_g1_i1 I would like the 6th column of file2 which would be 0.00 and  0.21

Comment: I have changed to original comment to a more usable example

Comment: Apologies Ed, I have put an example output this time. Thank you

Comment: OK but you posted 2 different possible outputs. Just pick THE OUTPUT you want and post that.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can give awk multiple input files. For your example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$2]=1;next}a[$1]{print $6}' file1 file2
```

I didn't test the above one-liner, but it should go. At least you get the idea.

If you don't know how many columns in your file1, as you said, you want to do a loop:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)a[$x]=1;next}a[$1]{print $6}' file1 file2
```

### update

edit for the new requirement:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$6;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=a[$i];print s;s=0}' f2 f1
```

The output of above one-liner: (take f1 and f2 as your input example file1 file2):

```
7
15
14
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although I didn't get any output when I tried this

Comment: @OllieWhite then make some small input examples also pls provide the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have put a simpler example up on the original comment now

Comment: @OllieWhite can you add the expect output also in code block?

Comment: I have put an example in now, thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Thank you @Kent, appreciate your patience. It has worked well on the original data